# why header of a section of a uitableview is abnormally tall when the uitableview is embedded to a uiviewcontroller?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I would like to make a page like this (i.e. a fix segmented controller on the top, with a uitableview appending beneath it):

[image]

So, this is the way I did it: I have added a segmented controller in a uiviewcontroller, then I append a uitableview under it. Here is the diagram in the storyboard:

[image] [image]

However, when it runs in the simulator, the header of the uitableview is abnormally tall.

I have no idea why it is like this. Am I going to a wrong direction? Thanks for any helps.

**UPDATE:**
This is the default setting of the uitableview. I didn't change any thing.

[image]

Comment: Have you returned correct height as you want?                         -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{ return yourHeight};

Comment: No, I didn't set the frame of the tableview programatically. the size of the tableview is (320, 370).

Comment: In xib are you setting the section's height?

Comment: I don't have a xib for this.

Comment: you can set your section's height in table view property from xib... Ok have you implemented this method?                                     (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{ return yourHeight};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your view controller in storyboard. In the Attributes inspector, uncheck "Adjust Scroll View Insets" and uncheck "Under Top Bars".

Answer (score 0):

You have placed Segment control in Tableview's header. But you had set some height to `tableview section header` via either xib or programmatically. That's why it leads to show this space.